# Define class methods inside Active Record class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Settings table from schema:

```
create_table "settings", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "value"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Settings table has these records:

```
{name: "notification_email", value: "hello@monkey.com"}
{name: "support_phone", value: "1234567"}
```

I want the **Setting.notification_email** function to return "**hello@monkey.com**" and respectively the **Setting.support_phone** function to return "**1234566**".

Here is what I have in my **setting.rb**:

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    all.each do |setting|
      define_method "#{setting.name}".to_sym do
        setting.value.to_s
      end 
    end 
  end 
end
```

But then when I enter Setting.notification_email in console, it gives me an error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `all' for #<Class:0x000000053b3df0>
    from /home/adam/Volumes/derby/app/models/setting.rb:7:in `singletonclass'
    from /home/adam/Volumes/derby/app/models/setting.rb:2:in `<class:Setting>'
    from /home/adam/Volumes/derby/app/models/setting.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use define_singleton_method - i.e.

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.all.each do |instance|
    define_singleton_method(instance.name) do
      instance.value.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `define_singleton_method` is for 1.9. The equivalent in 1.8 is `self.class.instance_eval` combined with `define_method` as before. Nice that this has been cleaned up.